# php echo info database using foreach change 0 to no

Tags: php, database, foreach

I have a database with some information. Using an for each statement im getting all the records from the database.

`$row2['test']` is in the database 0 or 1 with 0 being no and 1 being yes. My foreach statement works as it shows the records but i want to change the 0 in the test record into no and 1 into yes. I have tryed with an if statement but shamefully it doesn't seem to work.

```
foreach( $result as $row2 )

{ echo '<table ><tr><td>' . $row2['name'] . '</td></tr>' . '<tr><td>' . $row2['test'] . '</td></tr>' .'<tr><td>' . $row2['comments'] . '</td></tr>  </table><p>'; } ?></p>
```

Comment: Create an if statement or ternary operator. Easy fix. I'd post an answer but out of time so yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ternary operator, for example:

```
'<tr><td>' . ($row2['test']? 'yes' : 'no') . '</td></tr>'
```

Full code:

```
foreach( $result as $row2 )
{ 
    echo '<table ><tr><td>' . $row2['name'] . '</td></tr>' 
        . '<tr><td>' . ($row2['test']? 'yes' : 'no') . '</td></tr>' 
        . '<tr><td>' . $row2['comments'] 
        . '</td></tr>  </table><p>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function with the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to test the value with (check the manual for a full write up of what `empty` means, `0` is one of the values).

```
foreach( $result as $row2 ) { 
      $value .= !empty($row2['test']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
      echo '<table ><tr><td>' . $row2['name'] . '</td></tr>' . '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>' .'<tr><td>' . $row2['comments'] . '</td></tr>  </table><p>'; 
} ?></p>
```